# Difference between ~によって and ~を通じて (through, by means of)

Tags: grammar, nuances, definitions

It seems that both ~によって and ~を通じて (sometimes ~を通して) can be used to mean "through", "by means of", "via".  Both seem moderately but not very formal.

Are there any differences in nuance that dictate when I use one over the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [N1N2N3外国人のための日本語学習ブログ : 日本語能力試験２級文法　～を通して／～を通じて／～によって](http://blog.livedoor.jp/rosetea425/archives/133624.html),

> １．［名詞］＋を通（とお）して／［名詞］＋を通（つう）じて＝ **「～をとおって（to go/pass through)」「直接ではなく間に何か入って」「ずっと～」という意味。**

「~を通して、〜を通じて」 is used to express "the experience; go/pass thorough", "doing something using the medium such as person or things", "throughout ~".

> **体験を通して、学んだことは忘れない。「～をとおって（to go/pass through)」**

*You don't forget the things learnt by what you are actually doing.*

> **社長と話したい場合、秘書を通してアポをとる必要がある。**

*In case you would like to contact CEO, you need to make an appointment through the secretary.*

> **この辺は、一年を通して２０度以下になることはありません。**

*Around here, it does not get colder below 20℃ throughout a year.*

> 2.［名詞］＋によって／［名詞］＋による＋［名詞］＝**「～で」方法、手段を表す　（by means of/with~)**

And, によって is focusing on "the method" to acquire the outcome.

> **1. 
>   Q：彼はどうやった漢字を覚えたのかな？**　*How has he learnt kanji?*
>
> **A：彼は、何度も書くことによって、漢字を覚えたそうですよ。**

*He learned kanji by writing kanji again and again.*

> **2. 暴力{ぼうりょく} による解決{かいけつ}ではなく、話し合いによる解決を希望{きぼう}します。**

*Not achieving the solution by force and arms, but we hope to reconcile by argument.*

For 〜を通して、〜を通じて, which one preferred is according to the research [「Nを通じて」と「Nを通して」について](https://www.ninjal.ac.jp/event/specialists/project-meeting/files/JCLWorkshop_no5_papers/JCLWorkshop_No5_37.pdf),

The author says,

> 100万語当たりの頻度は、**「Ｎを通じて」は48.3語で、「Ｎを通して」は42.5語**で、「Ｎを通じて」のほうはやや多いが、大きな違いは見られなかった。しかし、表１、図１が示すように、サブコーパス別に見ると、出現の偏りが見られた。まず、**「Ｎを通じて」の用例が多いのは「白書」「新聞」「広報誌」「教科書」「国会会議録」である。この５つのサブコーパスはどちらというと、より書き言葉的であると言える。[!法律は「Ｎを通して」が0語であるのに対し、「Ｎを通じて」の出現頻度が20.4語である。法律は書き言葉的で、漢語を多用すると思われる。**

[image: サブコーパス別の100 万語あたり「Ｎを通じて」「Ｎを通して」の出現頻度]

「Ｎを通じて」is 48.3 in 1 million words, whereas 「Ｎを通して」is 42.5. And 「Ｎを通じて」is used more often in an annual report, newspaper, journals, textbook, the Diet Record. The frequency of appearance in law, 「Ｎを通して」is 0, but 「Ｎを通じて」 is 20.4 since the document in law is very written language and uses a lot of 漢語.

> 一方、「Ｎを通して」の出現が多いのは「教科書」「広報誌」「書籍」である。雑誌は多ジャンルの内容に分かれ、一概に書き言葉的あるいは話し言葉的とは言えない。

The「Ｎを通して」appears a lot in journals, textbook, books. Since magazine has a wide variety, you cannot conclude written language or spoken language unconditionally.

The author concludes,

> 第一、傾向として、先行研究でも指摘されているように、**「Nを通じて」「Nを通して」の両方が書き言葉的ではあるが、「Nを通じて」がより書き言葉的であることが検証できた**。第二、**「Nを通じて」が情報伝達の媒体としての用例、期間を表す用例が多く、それに対し、「Nを通して」は主体の積極的な持続行為により、何かを実現し、あるいは得られることを表す用例が多いことが分かった**。第三、**「Nを通じて」は公的な活動について述べる傾向にあり、「Nを通して」はどちらかというと私的な、具体的な事柄について述べる傾向にあることが分かった。** この第三の違いについてはコーパスのレジスターに影響されている可能性もあり、今後、別のデータで検証する必要がある

---

So, 「~を通じて」「~を通して」both are written language though, 「~を通じて」is used more often treated as written language. The followings are examples in the paper and I rearranged.

> 「Nを通じて」が情報伝達の媒体としての用例

- その話は山田さんを通じて相手にもつたわっているはずです

*The story should be delivered to the customer via Mr.Yamada.*

> 期間を表す用例

- その国は一年をつうじてあたたかい。

*The country is warm throughout a year.*

- このあたりは四季をつうじて観光客のたえることがない。

*Around here, the visitors never cease throughout four seasons.*

> それに対し、「Nを通して」は主体の積極的な持続行為により、何かを実現し、あるいは得られることを表す用例

- 子供は、学校で他の子供と一緒に遊んだり学んだりすることを通して、社会生活のルールを学んで行く

*Children learn the rule of the society by learning and playing with other children at school.*

Comment: Excellent resources and examples.  Responses like these are why I use this website.